# Twig 3 dimensional arrays

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, twig

before i tell you my problem i want to tell, that im really new to twig.

I have a 3 dimensional array from my database. It look like:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [cashin_id] => 1
            [money] => 500
            [date] => 2020-05-16 00:00:00
            [method] => Transfer
            [usage] => Produktplatzierung
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [cashin_id] => 1
            [money] => 1337
            [date] => 2020-05-16 19:19:27
            [method] => PayPal
            [usage] => Einzahlung 16.05.2020
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [cashin_id] => 1
            [money] => 1000
            [date] => 2020-05-16 19:21:02
            [method] => Banküberweisung
            [usage] => Auszahlung 21.05.2020
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [cashin_id] => 1
            [money] => 500
            [date] => 2020-05-16 19:22:29
            [method] => Transfer
            [usage] => Produktplatzierung
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [cashin_id] => 22
            [money] => 500
            [date] => 2020-05-16 19:22:37
            [method] => Transfer
            [usage] => Produktplatzierung
        )

)
```

i created a for loop in html to test if my sql query works well. In php it works fine.
But i still don´t know to show it in twig. I also used the search function but nothing works..

Here my loop in php:

```js
 echo "<table>";
            for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>".$recs[$row]['date']."</th>";
                echo "<th>".$recs[$row]['money']."</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
```

Maybe someone can show me how to solve my problem.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the records with `{% for x in y %}`, access attributes with dot notation or array notation

```html
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.id }}
    {{ row.date|date('d-m-Y') }}
    {{ row['money'] }}
    {{ row.usage }}
--------------------------------------
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/vubqg5)

---

*note: that's a 2D array btw*